# Call Java method from ms-sql-server

Tags: java, sql-server-2012

I need to call some java functions from sql server using a trigger. Is there any way to solve this requirement?, if yes, can you share it to me?,

I have already done this by Oracle , i have no idea about how to do this with ms-sql2012

Comment: take look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652238/run-c-sharp-code-inside-a-sql-agent-job)

Comment: You should call an external process as noted in the link in @A4L's comment. Oracle accepts writing stored procedures using Java code, but SQL Server doesn't, it doesn't even allow writing anything on .net languages either.